# C programming check digit

Tags: c

```
bool print_date(Date *d, char **argv) {

        if (isdigit(*argv+1)) {
                return printf("is d");
        } else {
                return printf("is not d");
        }

}
```

The above function don't work. *argv+1 is the user input, is it a string or what types when passing in? anyone can help?

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

  Date d;

  get_date(&d, argv);


 }
```

Comment: You need to say what doesn't work for you. However *argv is a char * (pointer to char), so *argv+1 is the address of the second character, not the character itself. You may have meant **(argv+1).

Comment: If you're not sure about the precendence, **use parenthesis**. Rather than `*argv+1` use `(*argv)+1` (or even `&(argv[0][1])`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*argv+1` computes the address to the first character of the 0-th argument (that is the executable name) and adds 1 to shift to second char of it.. I don't think this is what you want to do.

You could try by using `argv[1]`, this will mean the first argument after the executable name, as a `char *`.

Comment: of course it is not working, `isdigit` assumes a single char while using `argv[1]` will give you the whole string, not just a char. You should dereference it again to obtain the actual `char` type.

Comment: how to dereference it? i'm a beignning of C

Comment: @friends, try `argv[1][0]` -- this will be the first character of the first argument (and also consider checking argc to be sure that at least one argument was passed).

Comment: to dereference you use the `*` operator. Or you can go with user470379 solution that is quite straightforward..

Comment: @user470379 thaks, i've checked argv[1] is exactly what i want

Comment: if (isdigit(*argv[1])) {
  return printf("is d");
 } else {
  return printf("is not d");
 }

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that what you really want is `*(argv + 1)`. The way you have it written is that it will dereference the first character of the program, add one and then test if it is a digit.